# Erro ao acessar localhost após instalar Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer, localhost

Como eu disse em pergunta anterior eu estou iniciando meus estudos e já fiz a busca desse erro agora em vários locais.
Recentemente eu instalei o Composer e o Laravel em meu note e quando rodo o comando `php artisan serve` no `cmd` dentro das pastas dos projetos eles rodam perfeitamente no browser. Porém tenho um outros projetos que não estou desenvolvendo com Laravel e quando tento acessar outro projeto que tenho sem Laravel pelo caminho `localhost/librio`, que tem o index.php entre outros arquivos, o navegador dá o erro abaixo.

> Objeto não encontrado! A URL requisitada não foi encontrada neste
>   servidor. Se você digitou o endereço (URL) manualmente, por favor
>   verifique novamente a sintaxe do endereço.
>
> Se você acredita ter encontrado um problema no servidor, por favor
>   entre em contato com o webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.3.4

E por isso não funciona nenhum projeto, não consigo acessar nada pelo browser

Answer (score 0):

Após algum tempo pude verificar que havia o serviço MySQL80 rodando de forma automática e que ocupava a porta 3306, por esse motivo não deixava abrir o PHPMyAdmin nesta porta.
Deixei o serviço desativado.